# copy failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/packagename/databases/databasename.sqlite: open: failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, database-permissions, android-permissions

I have a problem with Nuxus 10 with normal user when they install my app and after run....and then it shown error

```
java.lang.Error: Error copying database => java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/packagename/databases/databasename.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

If I run with Nexus 10 with admin user, it works well.

AndroidManifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

I try to find the solution many times, but I still not found it.

Could you tell me the solution.
Thanks,

Comment: its not getting the database check your database name and path where you are coping..

Answer (score 0):

With the informations you provice I can just tell you that the database file seems not be existing. Check it with something like this:

```
if(new File("/path/to/database").exists()) {
    // database access code comes here
} else {
    // database does not exists. Create it!
    // create directories if needed
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Now I can create database but I don't have permission to open database with normal user on Nexus 10 (Nuxus 10 run on multi-user). but when I run on this device with admin user, it works well.

Comment: In that case you may need to put your database file in a shared directory. E.g. somewhere on the sdcard.

Comment: Just another idea use the path given by the os, so the users would have their own database. If i guess right than there are fore every user other data directories which are bot accessable by other users.